# How is it possible to show the menu of a chart with React Highcharts?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, menu, frontend, data-visualization

I cannot show the React Highcharts Menu while it should be shown by default.

I have tried to use the parameter "importing" in the options and enable it but it does not change anything.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just found out how to do it. You just need to add the "exporting" module from the package.

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
require("highcharts/modules/exporting")(Highcharts);
```

This is now working. I hope this may help some other folks with the same problem.